# Repo preferences over one to another?

Tags: apt, repository, preferences

if a same software (different version) are present in two repos both added in

> sources.list

then which one will get installed when I run install command

> apt-get install x

?

Also how can I choice one repo over another if both provide application with same name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(This answer is based on the default setup of Ubuntu, with default repository preference)*

If the same software has different versions, Apt will always try to use the most recent version of the software subject to dependency constraints.

*Please note that, Apt also look at the priority of a repository, if a higher priority of a repository has lower version, Apt won't upgrade the package. In default Ubuntu installation, all enabled repository has priority 500 except the backport repository, which has priority 100. So, if a software has higher versioned package in backport repository, that software will not be upgraded with `sudo apt-get install x` command. You need to explicitly tell apt to use that repository by using command like this: `sudo apt-get install x/precise-backports`. *

But, if two repo provide the same software with the same version, then Apt will install software from the repository which comes first in the `sources.list` file.

I'm quoting from [apt_preference manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/apt_preferences.5.html):

> ```
>    Several instances of the same version of a package may be available
>    when the sources.list(5) file contains references to more than one
>    source. In this case apt-get downloads the instance listed earliest in
>    the sources.list(5) file. The APT preferences file does not affect the
>    choice of instance, only the choice of version.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version is available where. To see which version will be installed, with the repositories in question added, you can run `apt-cache policy x`, to follow your example, and it will show you the installed version, and the candidate (which is the version which would be installed, if you install or upgrade).

Comment: how can I chose/change candidate which is selected by default ? I think default selection is based on version number ?

Comment: The candidate is always the newest version. As mentioned in the other answer, it will pick the first in the list if versions match. However, you shouldn't add extra sources to sources.list directly, but to new files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ instead; for cleanliness and maintainability. If you're trying to use another repository with the same version as Ubuntu, and the software isn't the same, then you should complain to the owner of that repository, with a bug report or something.